# Auto fill search box while redirected form particular url

Tags: wordpress

https://www.qaiglobalinstitute.com/calendar/, There is a search box in the above url above calendar. Now i want to get the search box auto filled with the text "design-thinking", when it is redirected from the url http://www.q-glue.com/.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Please Clear your Question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find searchform.php file of your current wordpress theme or create new one in your child theme, in searchform.php file you can find search form template.
Add these part of code before form, it can help you find a refer:

```
$refer = '';
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.q-glue.com/" ) {
    $refer = 'design-thinking';
}
```

Then add $refer variable as a value of your search input.
Final result will be something like it:

```
<?php

$refer = '';
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://www.q-glue.com/" ) {
    $refer = 'design-thinking';
}



?>
<form method="get" class="search-box" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="s"
        placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Type something to search', 'search form placeholder', 'unicorn' ); ?>"
        value="<?php echo $refer; ?>">
    <button type="submit"><i class="pe-7s-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Oleg,

Thanks for your help. But it didnt worked for me.

Thanks